# update shopify price via python with one API call

Tags: python, shopify

I'm working with the Shopify Python API, and I'd like to update the price of one of my products with a single API call. This is because their API is throttled and I'm updating a large number of items, so a 50% reduction in API calls will significantly improve my overall running time.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
product = shopify.Product.find(shopify_id)
product.variants[0].price = new_price
product.save()
```

This requires two API calls. Is there a way to update a price, given a shopify ID, with a single API call? I tried this (I was told on the forums that setting price on a Product would update all Variants):

```
product = shopify.Product(dict(id=shopify_id, price=new_price))
product.save()
```

and save() returned True, but the price did not update. Then I tried this:

```
product = shopify.Product(dict(id=shopify_id, price=new_price))
product.variants = [shopify.Variant()]
product.variants[0].price = new_price
product.save()
```

and save() returned False, product.errors.full_messages() returned ['Options are not unique'].

Comment: Why do you only want to use one API call? If the first lot of code is working fine what is the need to change it?

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr, their API is throttled and I'm updating a large number of products. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is pretty old but it's a good question that was never properly answered. It seems as though all the responses weren't exactly hearing what you were asking.

I have been working on a shopify app that requires updating many products at once which can take a while, especially if you need to call the API twice for each product (i.e. once to retrieve and again to update).

I had to dig into the source code to find this but the product class has a `add_variant` method that seems to do the trick.

```
product = shopify.Product(dict(id=123456789))
variant = shopify.Variant(dict(id=987654321, price=9.99))
product.add_variant(variant)
product.save()
```

This will *update* the product and allows you to basically perform a PUT request on the product. You can update as many or as little variants as you want and it won't disturb the others. Furthermore, it doesn't require the initial product call to retrieve the product you are updating.

Comment: Nice! This cuts API traffic in half for a large update which is pretty significant in my case.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake here. Although it seemed to have performed how I explained during my tests, it was due to the small amount of variants that appeared to be updated all at once when in fact `add_variant` simply calls "save" on the product each time which is in fact worse than what you were originally trying. For now, please uncheck my answer as correct and i'll continue looking into this.

Comment: you could try shopify.Variant(dict(id=shopify_variant_id, price=x)).save(), I have a note that this works but haven't had a chance to verify it

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you have the ID of the resource you want to update, just do a PUT call on it and you're good without first doing a GET. It is obvious that a product has no price, only variants do, hence your failure there. Your other choice is to just suck it up and GET the product or variant resource, update the variant's price(s) and do a PUT. Note that API calls are cheap. Trying to save on them is often more painful than just burning a couple off.

Comment: I clarified my question to explain why calling the API only once is important in my case. So there's no way to do this using just the product's ID, I need the ID of the variant I want to update?

Comment: The fact that the API is throttled is no reason to skimp on API calls. Since you have a large number of products, that throttle kicks in no matter how many API calls you shave. You are Yak shaving the wrong Yak. You should instead embrace the idea of ensuring your code works with the throttling, since you have to. Avoiding that is near impossible.